# python 2.7.3 not executing on apache 2.2

Tags: python, apache, localhost

Using Apache2.2
Python 2.7.3

in httpd.conf using  LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi-win32-ap22py27-3.3.so

python executes perfectly , but not on localhost

in localhost the following script is not being processed, nor are any errors appearing in error.log

What else to check for?

using test script

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7.3

# enable debugging
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

print "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\n"
print

print "Hello World!"
```

Answer (score 0):

mod_wsgi is a Apache module for running [WSGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Server_Gateway_Interface) applications. The example script you've provided is not a WSGI application, it's just regular CGI script.

Hello world in WSGI looks like this:

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/plain')])
    yield 'Hello World\n'
```

On the other hand, if you want to use old-fashioned CGI, you should use [Apache's mod_cgi](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/cgi.html). Note, that this is quite obsolete and inefficient way to do server-side programming, so I wouldn't recommend it for anything serious.

Comment: Thank you for your reply
Let me explain further  I ran a python25 script successfully in apache several years back -- the header to the program was

#! c:/python25/python.exe -u   

the code all ran and generated a complete webpage (at that time)

I edited the header to 
#! c:/python27/python.exe -u

today... all i see is python code

why?    I am trying to debug.. but cannot trap the error.. as the error.log  thinks all is ok -- no messages there

Comment: @albruno: you probably run it as CGI, not WSGI.